# Проблема с регуляркой

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение:

```
(?:\[([а-я ]+)(?:,([а-я ]+)-([а-я ]+))*\])
```

Есть текст:

```
[тут ок,это-не матчит,это-матчит]
```

Надо чтобы в итоге матчило следующие группы:

- тут ок
- это
- не матчит
- это
- матчит

Однако на деле получаю только последнюю пару после запятой `,X-X`, а то, что перед ней - не матчит. То есть для этого текста матчит так:

- тут ок
- это
- матчит

А надо, чтобы все пары `,(X-X),(X-X),(X-X), ... (X-X)]` добавлялись в разные группы.

Для проверки использую удобный сервис https://regexr.com/, если хотите быстро протестировать, что действительно не работает.

Как изменить регулярку, чтобы получить требуемое поведение? Использую `std::regex_constants::ECMAScript | std::regex_constants::collate` грамматику.

Comment: Это и не будет работать, повторяющиеся захватывающие группы всегда сохраняют последнее захваченное значение. В C# и Python PyPi regex есть возможность получить все захваченные значения, есть такая опция и в Boost, но там её лучше не использовать. Используйте `[^\][,]+`, [см. демо](https://regex101.com/r/K6cHCO/2) для получения всех вхождений (после предварительной валидации строки вашей регуляркой).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew хотите сказать с помощью стандартного `<regex>` это невозможно сделать?

Comment: Если нужна валидация, то можно в два прохода, если не нужна валидация, то используйте `[^\][,]+`, [см. демо](https://regex101.com/r/K6cHCO/2). Или `[а-я ]+(?:-[а-я ]+)*` ([демо](https://regex101.com/r/K6cHCO/3/))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew вы выполняете поиск подстрок в строке, а мне нужно полное совпадение строки + разбиение на группы полного совпадения

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew а как в 2 прохода вы говорите?

Comment: Приведите ваш код в вопросе. Я так понимаю, `(?:\[([а-я ]+)(?:,([а-я ]+)-([а-я ]+))*\])` используется в `std::regex_match`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew да, это так (с нужным экранированием символов)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew а, я понял, как в 2 этапа. Просто сохранять "хвост" и по нему уже новый `std::regex_match` делать. Попробую

Comment: Сейчас опубликую ответ.

Comment: Попробуйте как-то так - `std::regex val_rx(R"(\[[а-я ]+(?:,[а-я ]+-[а-я ]+)*\])");
    std::regex extract_rx("[а-я -]+");
    std::string foo = "[тут ок,это-не матчит,это-матчит]";
    if (std::regex_match(foo.begin(), foo.end(), val_rx)) {
        std::vector<std::string> result(std::sregex_token_iterator(foo.begin(), foo.end(), extract_rx),   std::sregex_token_iterator());
    }`

Comment: в 2 этапа в итоге получилось

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос то, что у вас получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Повторяющиеся захватывающие группы всегда сохраняют последнее захваченное значение. В C# и Python PyPi regex есть возможность получить все захваченные значения, есть такая опция и в Boost, но там её лучше не использовать. В C++ используйте два регулярных выражения, сначала ваше для предварительной валидации строки, а потом её часть для получения всех вхождений.

Регулярное выражение для валидации строки:

```
^\[[а-я ]+(?:,[а-я ]+-[а-я ]+)*]$
```

[Демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/9Khu2V/1)

Регулярное выражение для нахождения всех совпадений:

```
[а-я -]+
```

[Демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/9Khu2V/2)

Пример кода:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
// ...
std::regex val_rx(R"(\[[а-я ]+(?:,[а-я ]+-[а-я ]+)*\])");
std::regex extract_rx("[а-я -]+");
std::string foo = "[тут ок,это-не матчит,это-матчит]";
if (std::regex_match(foo.begin(), foo.end(), val_rx)) {
    std::vector<std::string> result(std::sregex_token_iterator(foo.begin(), foo.end(), extract_rx),
                                   std::sregex_token_iterator());
}
```

Comment: А почему опцию из `Boost` лучше не использовать?

Comment: @server В Boost это экспериментальная функция, которая снижает производительность. Кроме этого, нужно перекомпилировать библиотеку со специальным флагом.